# Option strict on disallows implicit conversion from string to double and double to string

Tags: vb.net

I have activated `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict`, and it appears to me that I get some errors:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Double'

and

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'Double' to 'String'.

Why do I get these errors?

If I remove `Option Strict`, I have no more errors. Some errors may not be fixed, so what should I do? Why use `Option Strict` if these errors occur?

```
TxtCheckDraws.Text = TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text - 1
TxtCheckList.Text = TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text - 1
```

Code:

```
Private Sub BttImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttImport.Click
    TxtBoxIntDraws.Clear()
    TxtBoxIntDraws.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\itemInfo.txt"))
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\itemInfo.txt"))
    Dim strLines() As String = Strings.Split(sr.ReadToEnd, Environment.NewLine)
    TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text = strLines.Length
    sr.Close()
    TxtCheckDraws.Text = TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text - 1
    TxtCheckList.Text = TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text - 1
    TxtBoxIntDraws.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines.Select(Function(l) String.Join(",", l.Split(",").Select(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s)))))
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be parsing `TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text` into an integer before taking 1 away from it. Because if text was put into this textbox, it would cause an error

Comment: If you hover over the problem lines, does it offer suggestions to correct them?

Comment: You need to be doing some error checking and, as @Cal-cium noted above, conversion from string to integer. Look at `Convert.ToInt32()` for your conversion. But you should first look at the text string in your `TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text` or use a `Try Catch` block to assure that the string only has numbers that fit in the range you require.

Comment: ... such as `TxtCheckDraws.Text = (CInt(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text) - 1).ToString()`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would only add that there needs to be some error checking on the user input in `TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text` or the program will crash.

Comment: @daShier It's worse than that: `TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text = strLines.Length` is only two lines up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the individual components of

```
TxtCheckDraws.Text = TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text - 1
```

`TxtBoxIntDrawsCount` is a TextBox. The `Text` property is a string. You try to subtract 1 from a string. This is not right. First, convert the text to an integer. The following will result in an integer.

```
Integer.Parse(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text) - 1
```

We have another TextBox `TxtCheckDraws` and another Text Property which is also a string. We can't assign an integer `Integer.Parse(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text) - 1` to a string. So we should convert it back to a string first.

```
TxtCheckDraws.Text = (Integer.Parse(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text) - 1).ToString()
```

This works as long as `TxtBoxIntDrawsCount` really had an integer in it. If it had, for example, the string "four" instead of the string "4", then you will have a problem. You will want to add some validation. There are many ways to do this and they are outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Please also check out @OliverJacot-Descombes answer because he included a good way to add the validation I had mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

`Option Explicit On` forces you to declare all variables. `Option Strict On` forces you to specify conversions explicitly. According to [Option Strict Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement):

> When Option Strict On or Option Strict appears in a file, the following conditions cause a compile-time error:
>
> - Implicit narrowing conversions
> - Late binding
> - Implicit typing that results in an Object type

The advantage is, that it results in a code that explicitly states what the programmer had in mind. You can still perform implicit widening conversions. e.g. an implicit conversion from `Integer` to `Double` still works.

Change your code to

```
TxtCheckDraws.Text = (CInt(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text) - 1).ToString()
TxtCheckList.Text = (CInt(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text) - 1).ToString()
```

This makes clear that you want to interpret the content of the textbox as an `Integer`, then want to subtract `1` from it and finally want to convert the result back to a `String`.

It is also a good idea to use `Integer.TryParse`, in case the user entered an invalid number

```
Dim number As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(TxtBoxIntDrawsCount.Text, number) Then
    TxtCheckDraws.Text = (number - 1).ToString()
Else
    ' Tell the user to enter a correct number
End If
```

See also:

- [@TLiebe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454583/880990) to [What do Option Strict and Option Explicit do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58188147/880990).
- Visual Basic .NET Language [Option Strict](https://riptutorial.com/vb-net/topic/4022/option-strict).
- Visual Basic .NET Language [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/vb-net/topic/4725/option-explicit).